# Push changes immediately to origin/master disabled in Sourcetree

Tags: version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Sourcetree 3.4.8 and I've found that the "Push changes immediately to origin/master" checkbox at the bottom of the File Status tab in my Workspace is disabled.

[image]

I've never had a problem using it in the past, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to activate anymore.  I have no problems doing each step separately (commit, then push), so it doesn't seem like a project / Git issue.  Not the end of the world, just a nuisance.  My best Google-Fu has turned up nothing related to this issue that I can find.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Look at this issue: [https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-13812](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-13812): looks like there are other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the problem only exists in the "No staging" view in SourceTree.

[image]

While in the "Split view staging" you are able to check the option to push immediately once you have staged at least one file.

[image]

So you can switch to the other view, stage one file, enable or disable the checkbox, unstage the file and switch back to the "No staging" view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I see that the issue is still open for SourceTree... I'm adding to your response to them so maybe they'll fix it up.  The workaround is helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

### The solution

#### Step 1

[image]

#### Step 2

Restart SourceTree.

#### Result

[image]

[jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-13812#comment-3303111](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-13812#comment-3303111)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SwissCodeMen, he found that this appears to be an open issue for Sourcetree.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-13812